# Визуализация баллистического движения на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

Делаю визуализацию движения баллистической ракеты. Суть в том, что нужно сделать программу с упрощенной моделью полета баллистической ракеты. Есть ли на языке Питон какие-либо библиотеки, чтобы можно было визуализировать эту модель? Достаточно, чтобы было видно как шарик/любая простая фигура летит по параболической траектории.

Comment: если вы можете написать функцию возвращающую высоту объекта от времени, то можете использовать модуль `matplotlib` для визуализации

Comment: нужно чтобы была именно анимация движения

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html

Answer (score 0):

Да есть, встроенная библиотека Turtle https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html